# Protobuf/Go cannot use literal * (type *) as type * in array or slice literal

Tags: go, proto

I have  a struct in my generated proto file that looks like this (simplified):

```
type Record struct {
    Field1           int64  `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=field1,proto3" json:"field1,omitempty"`
    Field2           []byte `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=field2,proto3" json:"field2,omitempty"`
}
```

and I'm trying to call it in my Go file

```
func foo(c messagepb.MessageServiceClient){
    fmt.Println("Starting to send message...")

    msgs := []*messagepb.MessageRequest{
        recordpb.Record{ //error msg here
            Field1:             1,
            Field2:             []byte{byte('a')},
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

but I get this error at the recordpb.Record line:

```
cannot use recordpb.Record literal (type recordpb.Record) as type *messagepb.MessageRequest in array or slice literal
```

If it helps, here's my `messagepb`:

`message.proto`

```
message MessageRequest { recordpb.Record records = 1; }
```

`message.pb.go`

```
type MessageRequest struct {
    Record               *recordpb.Record `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=record,proto3" json:"record,omitempty"`
}
```

I can't find anything useful about why this is happening... Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need one more set of curly braces. Can you show the Go definition of the MessageRequest type?

Comment: ... e.g. https://play.golang.com/p/zm5Xkc14Hhb

Comment: @mkopriva I've added the MessageRequest struct. I don't see the missing curly braces? I don't think curly braces are the issue here as well, if any is missing it's likely to be because of my attempt to shorten things :)

Comment: Considering the added definition of `MessageRequest`, I "don't think", I know that it is the missing curly braces.

Comment: Note that the extra set of curly braces is for initializing an element inside the slice. For example, the expression `[]T{}` is called a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), this expression initializes a slice of `T`s whose length and capacity are zero. It is however possible to write a composite literal that initializes the slice with as many elements as you want, for example the expression `[]T{T{}, T{}}` (a slice composite literal containing two composite literals of its elements) produces a slice whose length and capacity is 2.

Comment: Now in slice, array, and map literals you can elide the type when writing the composite literals of the elements, therefore `[]T{T{}, T{}}` can be shortened to this `[]T{{}, {}}`, the resulting slice will be the same.

Comment: If the elements in the composite literals have fields you need to initialize you can do so, as you normally would: `[]T{{F: <some_expr>}, {F: <some_expr>}}`. Do you see now what it is you're missing? Or is it still not clear?

Comment: @mkopriva ah I see now... That's important to know, thank you for taking the time to explain it! Huge appreciation for people like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are creating a slice of `[]*messagepb.MessageRequest` and then adding a `recordpb.Record` to it. `recordpb.Record` is not the same type as `*messagepb.MessageRequest`.

Given this type

```golang
type MessageRequest struct {
    Record *recordpb.Record `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=record,proto3" json:"record,omitempty"`
}
```

It looks like your `msgs` var should be

```golang
msgs := []*messagepb.MessageRequest{
    {
        Record: &recordpb.Record{
            Field1: 1,
            Field2: []byte{byte('a')},
        },
    },
}
```

@mkopriva 's comments above add some nice explanation to this.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this for so long. Atop of @mkopriva's comments on the {}, your answer made me realise I was missing a `Record` in my MessageRequest :)

Comment: @IceTea note that in a *struct literal*, if the number of values you're providing to it equals the number of *accessible* fields of that struct, you can omit the fields. In other words, in this case you *can* omit the `Record:` from the literal, just make sure the curlies are there: `[]*messagepb.MessageRequest{{&recordpb.Record{}}}` will work as long as `MessageRequest` has just one field and that field's type is `recordpb.Record`.

Comment: @IceTea in [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) there's a section on the rules that apply to struct literals. The ones that are related to the above comment are: *"An element list that does not contain any keys must list an element for each struct field in the order in which the fields are declared."* and *"If any element has a key, every element must have a key. "* https://play.golang.com/p/eHnPh_QhWPW